# Set variable equal to this value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to set the value of a js variable when clicking a link.

This is what I have attempted so far (simplified):

```
<a href="#?id=1" value="1" class="delete_link">Click to delete this row</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete_link").click(function(){
        var deleteID = $(this).val();
        alert(deleteID);

    });
}):
```

But this does not set the variable `deleteID` to 1. Am I selected the data in the link incorrectly?

Heres a jsfddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CjS8k/2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
var deleteID = $(this).attr("value");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CjS8k/3/

`value` isn't a valid attribute for `<a>` elements, meaning it won't be put into the `.value` property (which is what `.val()` will return). So instead, use:

```
<a href="#?id=1" data-value="1" class="delete_link">Click to delete this row</a>
```

with:

```
var deleteID = $(this).attr("data-value");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CjS8k/4/

Comment: Or just `$(this).data("value");`

Comment: @Antony Yeah, but I don't like using that :) I know jQuery automatically puts `data-*` attributes into `.data()`. Since it's an attribute, it seems static to me, so I would think to use `.attr()`. Using `.data()` implies, to me, that it's almost a "property". I like to use `.data()` only when I set things with `.data()`

Answer (score 2):

there "value"  is an attribute.

change your line  to

```
 var deleteID = $(this).attr("value");
```